# INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions KVM acceleration can NOT be used

Tags: kvm-virtualization

```
running Ubuntu 20.04 -- 8 core Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz -- 16GB ddr4
local.driver=lxd
```

I have an identical system running multipass just fine

```
multipass info --all
Please ensure multipassd is running and '/var/snap/multipass/common/multipass_socket' is accessible
```

Thanks a ton for your help

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: This is a hardware problem.  Enable Intel Virtualization Technology or vt-x, or vt-d or whatever name they gave it for your BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Rinzwind comment, I have enabled the **Intel Virtualization Technology** in the system BIOS and it worked for me.